Change position to shipping address items in order email - woocommerce
I need to add phone label in shipping addresses.
Because I had some problems to show shipping phone value in shipping email list, I used shipping_addresse_2 available in default list of shipping labels and I customized options. I was able to move this field where I wanted in checkout page, but in email order the position don't follow same logic and appears after shipping address_1
Here my actual code:
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'kd_arrange_checkout_fields', 9999);

function kd_arrange_checkout_fields($fields)
{

  $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']['label'] = 'Tel. referente';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']['class'][] = 'kc-shipping-phone-2';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']['placeholder'] = '';
  $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']['priority'] = 81;

  return $fields;
}

So, the question is: how to arrange shipping items in order emails position?
Thanks a lot.
